# When i need to reference my referenced assembly reference

Tags: .net, assemblies

Sorry i know that my question is complicated, some time when i reference an assembly i notes thats not important to reference also it's dependency but in other time the compiler  complaint
plz i want to know when it mandatory and when it not

Comment: Did I get this right - you're actually saying: "If I'm referencing an assembly that's depending on some other assembly, when do I need to add the reference for that assembly as well?"

Answer (score 2):

You *have* to add a reference to the "child" dependency if you're using a class in the "main" reference which in turn mentions that child dependency in its API. For example:

```
public class ClassInLibrary
{
    public void Foo(ClassInChildDependency x)
    {
    }
}
```

In order to use `ClassInLibrary`, you have to add a reference to the dependency so that the compiler knows what `Foo` looks like. Ditto if the class inherits from another class in the dependency library, etc.

If you're using a class which has *no* connection to the dependency, you should be okay at compile-time... but you may well need the dependency at execution time anyway.